# Is it possible to prove Gödel’s 1st Incompleteness theorem without the use of self referential statements

Tags: logic, incompleteness

Is it possible to prove Gödel’s 1st Incompleteness theorem without the use of self referential statements?

I have searched for various proofs of the first incompleteness theorem and all of them use some sort of self-reference or the other(usually indirectly however). Is this the only way to prove it?

Comment: Not sure if reduction would be an alternative.

Comment: Sorry I’m a high school student(so I’m not very clear on this). What do you mean by reduction?

Comment: This is a fine question, but has been asked before.

Comment: Oh, no problem at all